# Array to string conversion on PDO::execute()

Tags: php, database, pdo

I get this error

> Notice: Array to string conversion in coolFile on line 54

Now, the line 54 is the following

`$result = $stmt->execute($par)`;

where `$par` is:

```
$par = array (
            'eNo' => $no,
            'eType' => $type,
            'eString' => $string,
            'eFile' => $file,
            'eLine' => $line,
            'eContext' => $context,
            'eTime' => time(),
            'eIp' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
        );
```

And `$stmt` is `$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);` and `$pdo` is the instance of the `PDO` class.

I feel a bit confused: Is PHP warning me that it has to convert an array to string?
Why cannot he accept such an array in a function that expects an array to be passed as parameter?

Comment: Are any of those variables in the array an array? More than likely this is the case. Since `PDOStatement::execute` only accepts and array of scalar values, any other values (like an array) are converted to a string.

Comment: @Kevin Peno, no: `handler($no, $string, $file, $line, $context)` this is the error handler for PHP errors (set with `set_error_handler()`). As you can notice the parameters of the handler are never arrays.

Comment: `var_dump( $par )` and post your output. How am I supposed to assume that you are not getting arrays?

Comment: What? `$context` is an empty array? @Kevin Peno, PHP error handlers are all equal. You should know that every parameters is a string a part from the error NO. But apparently neither i do, so... Why is `$context` an empty array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight form the PHP `set_error_handler` page, the signature for a handler function is:

```
handler ( int $errno , string $errstr [, string $errfile [, int $errline [, array $errcontext ]]] )
```

As you can see, PHP will send you an array for context. If you don't need this, remove it or find a way to make it a scalar value.

`errcontext`

`The fifth parameter is optional, errcontext, which is an array that points to the active symbol table at the point the error occurred. In other words, errcontext will contain an array of every variable that existed in the scope the error was triggered in. User error handler must not modify error context.`

Comment: I posted my answer already. But i also guess it doesn't really matter that much if a choose my answer instead of yours so (also you will get reputation, i won't)...

Comment: Same time, no foul :P Glad we figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Basically it seems that the fifth parameter of `set_error_handler()` is an array according to the Manual:

> The fifth parameter is optional, errcontext, which is an array that points to the active symbol table at the point the error occurred. In other words, errcontext will contain an array of every variable that existed in the scope the error was triggered in. User error handler must not modify error context.

So the problem was not regarding the main array, but the array inside the main array.
PS: I swear i didn't know that, i was pretty sure the error context was a string.

Comment: It's always been this way, but no one ever uses it. :P